# Unable to request ads from server due to network error- IMA SDK Error and iOS

Tags: android, ios, imasdk

I am using IMA SDK (iOS - Swift) to play pre-roll ads(Wrapper VAST 3.0)
But when i use this url "http://fusioniprojects.com/rnd/addpod/adpods.xml"

I am getting following error in my log 
                                  "**Unable to request ads from server due to network error.**"

and when i am using the url of this type -

"https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?sz=640x480&iu=/124319096/external/single_ad_samples&ciu_szs=300x250&impl=s&gdfp_req=1&env=vp&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&cust_params=deployment%3Ddevsite%26sample_ct%3Dredirecterror&correlator="

its running fine.

I fallow the solution of this problems from here ( ref - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ima-sdk/DqE5GruzwwA),

Now its Playing only 1 ad in Android project,not multiple ad and not working for iOS at all.

It may be that I am doing some things wrong in my iOS project but i also downloads the sample project from IMA-SDK (ref - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-ima-ios/releases), But it did not help me to come out with this problems, I am getting same error.I don't know how is it running (at least 1 ad) for the Android project after changes on the server.

Is it problems of IMA-SDK? or am I doing something wrong?

Used IMA SDK version 3.3.1 in iOS.

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache sever then To add the CORS authorization to the header using Apache, simply add the following line inside either the Directory, Location, File or VirtualHost sections of your server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file: below of the code put inside .htacces file.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*'
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```